# Creating plots from 2-D values generated in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I'm creating a trail of the (x,y) co-ordinates generated in a for-loop. But the plot pops up and it's blank. Can someone help the noob out?

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

x = 0
y = 0

dx = 0
dy = 0
v = 2

n=100
pl.figure()
pl.hold(True)

for i in range(1,n):
    dx = random.uniform(-2,2)
    x = x+dx
    y += ((v**2 - dx**2)**(0.5))*(random.randint(-1,1))
    pl.plot(x,y)
    print(x,y)

pl.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to plot a *line* for each of your random points: the graph is blank because each single point isn't connected to any other. You could try building a list of the points and plotting that list as a line graph:

```
xarr, yarr = [], []
for i in range(1,n):
    dx = random.uniform(-2,2)
    x = x+dx
    y += ((v**2 - dx**2)**(0.5))*(random.randint(-1,1))
    xarr.append(x)
    yarr.append(y)
pl.plot(xarr,yarr)

pl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
pl.plot(x,y)
```

plots in the default style, which is to *not* plot the individual points, but just the lines between points.  Since you are plotting one point at a time, nothing is appearing.  You can either plot the points in such a way that they show up:

```
pl.plot(x,y,'ko')
```

This will mean that you do not see the sequence, but just the individual points.  A better solution would be to keep track of the points and then plot them all at once:

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 0
y = 0

dx = 0
dy = 0
v = 2

n=100
plt.figure()

xs = []
ys = []
for i in range(1,n):
    dx = random.uniform(-2,2)
    x = x+dx
    y += ((v**2 - dx**2)**(0.5))*(random.randint(-1,1))
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)

plt.plot(xs,ys)    
plt.show()
```

Note that you don't need `plt.hold(True)` any more because you are only making one call to `plt.plot()`

Also note that I've changed `pl` to `plt` in the second example, since this is an extremely strong convention when using `matplotlib` and it is a good idea to follow it, for code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a format string. Try to replace

```
pl.plot(x,y)
```

with

```
pl.plot(x,y,'r+')
```

or any other kind of format documented at http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot